# Coordinates of a vector under a basis in a Hilbert space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, coordinate-systems

Given an arbitrary basis $\{m_1, \dots, m_n \}$of a Hilbert space $H$ (or just think it as $\mathbb R^n$, and I think the methods should be the same) with given inner product, how can we find the coordinates of a vector $v$ in the space?
Is there a solution in some elegant form for the coordinates?

I am thinking about first apply Gram-schmidt method to orthogonalize the basis, but feel the derivation too complicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector of coordinates $x$ can be easily found by a linear system $Ax = b$
where $A$ is the Gram Matrix of the base ${\{m_1,...,m_n\}}$ and $b$ is the vector $\{<v,m_i>\}$

Comment: They are given explicitly by the linear system above!

Comment: I see. Why is it the solution to the equation?

Comment: Well. Write $v$ as a linear combination of the basis elements and then check out the inner product with another element basis.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how $\{m_1,...,m_n\}, v$ are "given". If they are given as coordinate column-vectors in some other basis, then the solution to the matrix equation $Ax=v$ where $A = [m_1 \mid m_2 \mid \dots \mid m_n]$ gives the coordinates in the new basis. If their coordinates are unknown, but, for example, we can compute their inner products, then the coordinates can be found from $A^TAx=A^Tv$ as in Tal's answer.